# Calling StoredProcedure in Subsonic throws Error

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic

I setup a simple select SP to return some rows use the templates to generate the StoredProcedures.cs file and then attempt to call the SP and get a Dataset back;

```
SubSonic.Schema.StoredProcedure sp = GetSPData(userID);
var data = sp.ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0];
```

The errror I receive is this:

```
The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.
```

I am using Subsonic v3.0.0.3.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post the code for GetSPData?

Comment: Its a complicated long SP that contains loads of selects. The SP runs fine if you just execute it from say Query Analyzer, it just returns about 8 columns of nvarchars and a single int (pkid).

Comment: I see this post in Google Groups; http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/browse_thread/thread/145e7ba321ae48bf#

So a bug then? Surely I am not the only one trying to use Stored Procedures with Subsonic 3!

Comment: Ok I found this; http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/commit/d1881c125265370ca73016d82be207c863acd964 in the Git repo about where they fixed it. Wonder if the latest build didnt include these bits. Grrr...

Comment: Aha so that fix was on 7/27 and the latest build was built 7/15. That explains that. Now unto getting a newer build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if answering my own question is bad mojo, but since I figured out the issue I figured I would share for potentially others benefit.

Seems there was a fix for executing stored procedures for Subsonic but it didn't make it into the 3.0.0.3 release. From the [GitHub](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/tree/master) repository download a tarball, unzip, open in VS2008, rebuild (be sure you make a Release build) and use that Subonic.Core.Dll versus the one in the 3.0.0.3 release. This works and the Stored Procedure is successfully executed.

Woot!